# Find column break's location in word document by C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a Word document. In this document I have a column break. Now, I want to get the location of this column break. I hope you can help me to solve my problem.
Thanks for your watching.

```
int ColumnBreak()
{
    if (_activeDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText: "^n"))
             MessageBox.Show("This document has break column");
//I don't know how to find the position of this column break
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: How much you tried? can you please paste your code?

Comment: I've just update my code, but it's not work.